# Intersections of open sets

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space such that
$$\bigcap_{i\in I} \overline{U_i} = \overline{ \textrm{int}\bigcap_{i\in I} U_i }$$
holds for every family of open sets $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ in $X$. I would like to know if this class of spaces has a name or any other (more useful) characterization.

Comment: One consequence: taking an open set $U$ and the exterior of this open set we see that closure of any open set must be open.

Answer (score 0):

As Kavi pointed out, a necessary condition is
that the space be extremally disconnected.

An Alexander space is a space for which
any intersection of open sets is open.
A sufficient condition is that the space
be an Alexander space.